# Tomcat in Eclipse not starting my webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

I'm trying to do something which is normally a no brainer. I want to start my webapp in Tomcat from Eclipse.

Here the steps I followed:

- Creating the server using the server wizard
- Adding the webapp

The server is starting without any problem, but it's not starting the webapp. I should get the webapp starting logs, but I only get the standard Tomcat logs, like it would log if I started it without a webapp. And trying to access the webapp in a browser gets me a 404 error. Any ideas?

Last thing: when I add the war file manually in the webapp folder, it deploys, starts and runs without any problem.

I'm using Eclipse Luna with Tomcat 7.0.55 and the JDK 1.6, on a Mavericks Mac. I'm building my project with Maven 3.

**Edit:** After some searching, it seems the problem happens at the deployment step. When I look in my `target/majrouting-web-1.1.4` folder, I can see my WEB-INF, META-INF, css, img, and js folders. But when I look in my deployment folder in `wtpwebapps`, only the WEB-INF exists. Still, when I deploy manually (copying the war file in the /webapp folder and starting Tomcat), it's deploying and working ok. The content of the war file seems ok, also. I don't get it.

Comment: As I got no valuable answer, I switched to Netbeans, and it worked almost immediately. If you know the answer, though, I'm still interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced same problem ,and here is my solution it works for me:

right click the project->**Properties**->**Deployment Assembly**->**Add..**,
select **Folder** and select the folder that contains the js/css/other resources, and after restart it works.

I encounter this while update eclipse from Kepler to Neon, this step is not required in Kepler. (at least in my side)

Answer (score -2):

Did you added the application to tomcat?

http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst%2Fhtml%2Fwst-integration%2Fdeployment.html